# What is a startup form constructor?

Tags: c#, vb.net, constructor

I need to put following code in the constructor of my startup form.

```
JohnKenedy.BusinessSQLEXPRInstaller _ins =
    new JohnKenedy.BusinessSQLEXPRInstaller(
        " _ <Installation Display Name>",
        "localhost",
        "<New database instance name>",
        "<new database name>",
        "<database password>",
        "<database backup filename>");

if (_ins.IsDone == false)
    _ins.ShowDialog();

if (_ins.IsRestart == true)
{
    Application.Exit();
    this.Close();
    return;
}
```

What is a constructor and how do I access it?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor is the method that's named after the class (which in this case is your form).  This is going to set the code off before your form shows and people will be wondering what is taking so long for the form to show up.  Even if that were not a problem, this looks like part of the installation for your app which you wouldn't want to put here.  The fact that you're asking this question though is an indication that you're just learning so that's why I'm answering your question but the reason you got downvoted is because you're asking for help in doing something that you wouldn't normally want to do.

First you should read up on the differences between the constructor and form's Load event.  If you do need to fire something off that's going to take a while and have to do it here then I would recommend doing it from the Load event rather than the constructor.  If there's an error and it happens in the constructor it may be more difficult to debug than if it's in the Load event and the form object is already fully instantiated.